# Scratch orgs - non deterministic issue with standard application

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

Initial metadata push to scratch org sometimes is successful and sometimes fails for the same commit (metadata state) for some reason.

Issue is with the following element:
`src/main/default/applications/standard__LightningSalesConsole.app-meta.xml`

And error message that shows up:

> Cannot create a new component with the namespace: standard.  Only
>   components in the same namespace as the organization can be created
>   through the API

As I wrote above, the strangest thing is that it's not deterministic, it sometimes fails and sometimes goes through for the same commit.

In the scratch org definition file I have enabled the required features:

```
"features": [
    "LightningSalesConsole",
    "LightningServiceConsole",
    ...
],
```

I know I can add this element to `.forceignore` but I would prefer to keep tracking this element since I am using this standard app. Any ideas why it's inconsistent? I don't recall having such issues on another project but there we used only standard Lightning Sales Console, and not standard Lightning Service Console that fails here.

Comment: Just to clarify. The first statement: it isn't scratch org _creation_ that fails, rather pushing meta to a scratch org, right?

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks for the comment

Comment: Is it possible something asynchronous is happening? e.g. you add the features, and then it takes some seconds/minutes until the standard console apps exist for you to update.

Comment: Actually, might be a case since this error usually occurs for scripts run by Jenkins where the commands are executed immediately one after another and I don't recall experiencing it when I made create and push on my own. I will do some additional testing, thanks Charles for the idea

Comment: See this too. Also saw a similar, non-deterministic error when pushing profiles that included an `<applicationVisibilities>` referencing `standard__LightningSalesConsole`

Comment: Yep, I sometimes have to wait up to 10 minutes for Service Console to appear in my app launcher. Funnily, it's infrequent enough that I usually forget and end up googling my way to this thread.